# convert word document to pdf

Tags: c#, silverlight, pdf, ms-word

I have a `RadGridView` which should be exported to doc,pdf, csv and xls format. The export to doc, csv and xls works fine... but there's something wrong in exporting it to pdf format. The export to pdf works but the columns that i hide still shows...

So i just thought of exporting the `RadGridView` to pdf by: exporting it to word then convert it to pdf programmatically...

By the way, here's my code for exporting to word.

```
//export to doc
private void Export_Doc(object sender, System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    ExportDialog("doc", "Word", ExportFormat.Html);
}
private void ExportDialog(string extension, string selectedItem, ExportFormat format)
{
    SaveFileDialog dialog = new SaveFileDialog();
    dialog.DefaultExt = extension;
    dialog.Filter = String.Format("{1} files (*.{0})|*.{0}|All files (*.*)|*.*", extension, selectedItem);
    dialog.FilterIndex = 1;
    if (dialog.ShowDialog() == true)
    {
        using (Stream stream = dialog.OpenFile())
        {
            GridViewExportOptions exportOptions = new GridViewExportOptions();
            exportOptions.Format = format;
            exportOptions.ShowColumnFooters = true;
            exportOptions.ShowColumnHeaders = true;
            exportOptions.ShowGroupFooters = true;

            RadGridView1.Export(stream, exportOptions);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using word via OLE automation (Note: word COM is not re-entrant - make sure not to call this concurrently from different threads):

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Interacts directly with Word via COM to convert a document to PDF
    /// Must have the Microsoft enhancement installed to support Save As PDF
    /// in the word file menu
    /// "2007 Microsoft Office Add-in: Microsoft Save as PDF or XPS" - SaveAsPDFandXPS.exe
    /// </summary>
    private void ExportToPDFUsingWord(object sourceDoc, string destPDF)
    {
        object m = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;
        object readOnly = true;
        object myFalse = false;
        object isVisible = false;
        object matchCase = false;
        object matchWholeWord = true;
        object saveChangesWhenQuitting = false;

        //Debug("Connecting to word");
        _Application oWordApp = new Application();
        _Document oWordDoc = null;
        Documents oWordDocs = null;

        try
        {
            // load the source file
            //Debug("Opening " + sourceDoc);
            oWordDocs = oWordApp.Documents;
            oWordDoc = oWordDocs.Open(ref sourceDoc, ref m, ref readOnly, ref m, ref m, ref m, ref m, ref m, ref m, ref m, ref m, ref isVisible, ref m, ref m, ref m, ref m);

            if (oWordDoc != null)
            {
                try
                {
                    WdExportFormat paramExportFormat = WdExportFormat.wdExportFormatPDF;
                    bool paramOpenAfterExport = false;
                    WdExportOptimizeFor paramExportOptimizeFor = WdExportOptimizeFor.wdExportOptimizeForPrint;
                    WdExportRange paramExportRange = WdExportRange.wdExportAllDocument;
                    int paramStartPage = 0;
                    int paramEndPage = 0;
                    WdExportItem paramExportItem = WdExportItem.wdExportDocumentContent;
                    bool paramIncludeDocProps = true;
                    bool paramKeepIRM = true;
                    WdExportCreateBookmarks paramCreateBookmarks = WdExportCreateBookmarks.wdExportCreateWordBookmarks;
                    bool paramDocStructureTags = true;
                    bool paramBitmapMissingFonts = true;
                    bool paramUseISO19005_1 = false;

                    // 
                    // Export the file to PDF. 
                    //Debug("Exporting to " + destPDF); 
                    oWordDoc.ExportAsFixedFormat(destPDF,
                        paramExportFormat, paramOpenAfterExport,
                        paramExportOptimizeFor, paramExportRange, paramStartPage,
                        paramEndPage, paramExportItem, paramIncludeDocProps,
                        paramKeepIRM, paramCreateBookmarks, paramDocStructureTags,
                        paramBitmapMissingFonts, paramUseISO19005_1,
                        ref m);
                }
                finally
                {
                    //Debug("Closing " + sourceDoc); 
                    oWordDoc.Close(ref saveChangesWhenQuitting, ref m, ref m);
                }
            }
            else
                throw new FileLoadException("Documents.Open returned null for file \'" + sourceDoc + "\', perhaps use comexp.msc and change DCOM->Word97-2003 Identity to Interactive user");  // if you are running from within a service then Word behaves differently - it is designed as a user application which must have a user interface
        }
        finally
        {
            // close word and cleanup            
            //Debug("Quitting Word"); 
            oWordApp.Quit(ref saveChangesWhenQuitting, ref m, ref m);

            //Debug("Releasing RCWs");
            Release(oWordDocs);
            oWordDocs = null;
            Release(oWordDoc);
            oWordDoc = null;
            Release(oWordApp);
            oWordApp = null;

            //Debug("Collecting garbage");
            GC.Collect();  // forces the garbage collector to run and might release any references that the RCW still has
            GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
            //Debug("Word objects finished");
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Using DevExpress (below code only works with RTF format - which doesn't necessarily work with all Word's functionality):

```
private void ExportToPDFUsingDevExpress(string sourceDoc, string destPDF)
    {
        DevExpress.XtraPrinting.PrintingSystem printingSystem1 = new DevExpress.XtraPrinting.PrintingSystem();
        DevExpress.XtraRichEdit.RichEditControl richEditControl1 = new DevExpress.XtraRichEdit.RichEditControl();
        richEditControl1.LoadDocument(sourceDoc);
        DevExpress.XtraPrinting.PrintableComponentLink link = new DevExpress.XtraPrinting.PrintableComponentLink(printingSystem1);
        link.Component = richEditControl1;
        link.CreateDocument();
        link.PrintingSystem.ExportToPdf(destPDF);
    }
```